# How to handle issues when we run out of connections to database?

Tags: database, database-connection

I am looking for what are the commonly used / best practices in industry.

Assume the following hypothetical scenario:
If my app server accepts 200 user requests, and each of them need DB access.
But my DB max_connections are 100.

If all 200 users request at the same time, but we have only 100 max_connections, what happens to the other requests, which were not served max connections ?

In real world:

1. will remaining 100 requests be stored in some sort of a queue on apps servers, and kept waiting for DB connections ?
2. do we error out ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if your database server can only handle 100 connections, and all of your web connections "require database access," you must ensure that no more than 100 requests are allowed to be ***active*** at any one instant.   This is the “ruling constraint” of this scenario.   (It may be one of many.)

You can *accept* "up to 200 simultaneous connections" on your server, but you must *enqueue* these requests so that the limit of 100 *active* requests is not exceeded.

There are many, many ways to do that:   load balancers, application servers, even Apache/nginix directives. Sometimes, the web-page is only a front-end to a process that is broken-out among many different servers working in parallel. No matter how you do it, there must be a way to regulate how many requests are active, and to queue the remainder.

Also note that, even though you might have “200 active connections” to your web server, it is highly unlikely that all 200 of these clients “clicked their mouse at *precisely* the same time.”   Requests come in at random rates and therefore might never encounter any sort of delay at all. But your system must nonetheless be engineered to handle the worst case.